# Loop throug column and paste values to an existing workbook

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy-paste

Hi this is my first post and i am newbie when it comes to VBA.
So i tried the last 6 hours to accomplish  one task.

I already managed to get the code for the For each loop and it works and copies the value to the existing workbook. But i couldnt find out why it always copies the value to A2 and not further to A3/A4/A5 and so on .

I tried these piece of code  " range = range + 1 " but i keep getting runtime errors and it still copies the values to A2 and overwrites it when it gets a new value from the loop.

I think its only a litte change needed but i cant figure it out. :(

```
Sub copie1()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim targetsheet As Worksheet
Dim target As Range
Dim rngTemp As Range

Set wkba = ActiveWorkbook

Worksheets("cop1").Activate
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LT = Cells(Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rngTemp = Range("X2:X" & LT)

   Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\path......."
        Set targetsheet = Worksheets("Data")
     Set target= targetsheet.Range("A1")

For Each cell In rngTemp
If cell > 0 Then

target.Offset(1, 0) = cell.Value

        End If


      target = target+1  '// is this right? 

Next cell





End Sub
```

my goal is the loop through column X in a Workbook and copy every single data that is bigger than 0 ( because there are empty cells & cells with value 0)
and paste it in an existing workbook in range A2/A3/A4 and so on

Comment: `target = target + 1` is implicitly doing `target.Value = target.Value + 1`, which is right if that's what you mean to be doing. Is it?

Comment: Use a counter. counter = 1
If cell.Value > 0 Then
    targetSheet.Range("A" & counter).Value = cell.Value
    counter = counter + 1
End If

Comment: i used a counter and now it copys all the values over  but it skips cells ? for example A2 is filled and then blank cells till A21 and bunch of copied values and again blank cells ?

Comment: @SibSib1903, I have provided an example to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add the number one to a Range object.

Try replacing `target = target+1  '// is this right?` with:

```
Set target = target.Offset(1)
```

Does this resolve the problem?

Comment: looks like i needed a counter  this solution lead to an runtimeerror

Comment: What line throw the error? Or are there any error details? You don't specifically need a counter, I don't think. The `For Each cell in rngTemp` should limit the range upon which you are searching.

Answer (score 0):

SibSib1903, I have added below a simple example that you can easily adapt to your own requirements. It looks at all cell values in column A and any numeric value greater than zero is copied to column C starting in row 1. For example, if column A contains 45 rows with data, and only three of these rows have a numeric value greater than zero, these three values will copied in column C in the first three rows.

```
Public Sub copieTest()
Dim ws As Worksheet, cell As Range, rngX As Range
Dim tmpVal As Variant, counter As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("cop1")
Set rngX = ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

counter = 1
For Each cell In rngX
    tmpVal = Val(Trim(cell.Value))
    If tmpVal > 0 Then
        ws.Range("C" & counter).Value = tmpVal
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next cell
Set rngX = Nothing: Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```